# Mixing Associative Arrays

Tags: php

I have a function that gets from the DB all the data of the users from different tables.
I am using `PDO` and what returns for each `SELECT` is an `associative array`.

What I want is that the function will return only one `array` including all the info taken from the DB. So a big `array` with all the user data.

The problem is that I am getting errors because I can't simply merge more `arrays` or I'll have `Array to string conversion error`.

How can I mix all the `arrays` in one understandable `array`?

```
function userInfo($uID, $pdo) {
    $user = PDOselect('user', '*', array('id_user'=> $uID), $pdo);
    $user_registration = PDOselect('user_registration', '*', array('id_user'=> $uID), $pdo);
    $user_addfields_anagraphic = PDOselect('user_addfields_anagraphic', '*', array('id_user'=> $uID), $pdo);
    $user_addfields_legal = PDOselect('user_addfields_legal', '*', array('id_user'=> $uID), $pdo);
    $user_addfields_public = PDOselect('user_addfields_public', '*', array('id_user'=> $uID), $pdo);
    return .....
}
```

Comment: you can solve this 2 ways. 1 create a single sql statement to return one data set or have a function to construct a single array by iterating over the multiple arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **+** operator or **array_merge()** to concatenate two arrays.

**+ operator:**
Appends into the first array the elements of the second one. For keys that exist in both arrays, the matching elements of the second array will be ignored.

**array_merge():**
Appends into the first array the elements of the second one. If there are elements in both arrays with the same key, the behaviour of this functions depends of:

1. *the key is numeric:* the element will be appended and the key
   renumbered
2. *the key is a string:* the later value will replace the
   first one.

Example:

```
// array ( [colour] => red, [0] => 2, [1] => 4 )
$array1 = array( "colour" => "red", 2, 4);      

// array ( [0] => a, [1] => b, [colour] => green, [shape] => circle, [2] => 4
$array2 = array( "a", "b", "colour" => "green", "shape" => "circle", 4);
```

Using ( + ):

```
$result = $array1 + $array2;
// $result: array ( [colour] => red, [0] => 2, [1] => 4, [shape] => circle, [2] => 4 )
```

Using (array_merge):

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
// $result: array ( [colour] => green, [0] => 2, [1] => 4, [2] => a, [3] => b, [shape] => circle, [4] => 4 )
```

I hope this be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should do something like this:

```
function userInfo($uID, $pdo) {
    return array(
        'user' => PDOselect('user', '*', array('id_user'=> $uID), $pdo),
        'user_registration' => PDOselect('user_registration', '*', array('id_user'=> $uID), $pdo,
        'user_addfields_anagraphic' => PDOselect('user_addfields_anagraphic', '*', array('id_user'=> $uID), $pdo,
        'user_addfields_legal' => PDOselect('user_addfields_legal', '*', array('id_user'=> $uID), $pdo,
        'user_addfields_public' = PDOselect('user_addfields_public', '*', array('id_user'=> $uID), $pdo,
        // etc..
    );
}
```